# How to use pyqt gui window in two different python file

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I have created a pyqt5 window in abcd.py file with required labels and button and text.

Now, I have created efgh.py file in the same directory.

How can we import that window into efgh.py?

Thanks

Comment: Either the question is improperly asked, or you just `from abcd import SomeUiClass`, assuming you've created a class (and you should've).

Comment: @musicamante, I have created a super class for the PyQt5 GUI window.

Comment: Then just import it, I don't see where's the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I have imported the class already. While creating any button or label, how to pass it to class to display in created window.